# E-ink tablet as substitute for textbooks

Tags: tablet, e-ink

I am looking for an E-ink tablet that can be used well as a **substitute for physical college textbooks**.

1. It should have a pdf-reader that is versatile in the sense that it has many features that are useful for reading textbooks:

   - easily put bookmarks on pages; (preferably multiple types of bookmarks)
   - easily go to chapters based on contents section;
   - easily switch back and forth bookmarked pages, or between chapters; (preferably easily switch between pdfs)
   - draw notes in existing pdf files with a pen.
   - easily go through such notes or bookmarks.
2. Easily transfer files to the tablet via wifi
3. Bonues: taking notes in a note-taking app.
4. doesn't necessarily have to do anything else (e.g. no youtube, email, etc)

One such tablet that comes to mind is "reMarkable". However, from what I've seen online, it is very limited when it comes to bookmarks, content section, etc.

**What are the best e-ink tablets that satisfy these requirements, and can be used as a good substitute for college textbooks?**

Comment: The pen part I think may be a bit of a hold up. Most of these tablets are either intended for drawing or reading, not schoolwork–though I'm as surprised as you are that no one has capitalized on this void well, given the potentially lucrative nature of education. Since you'll probably need a laptop anyways for college, what about getting one that can handle your textbooks as well? The Surface Pro comes to mind, but there are plenty of other options.

Answer (score 1):

An E-reader that's similar in size to the ReMarkable that you mentioned is the *BOOX note air*. It is pen compatible, has a shared display options(book one side notes on the other for example) and can sync both with note taking apps as well as some cloud options. from what I can tell it seems to be made with your requirements in mind

Another option is the *Kobo libra*. It lacks some of the features, most notably a pen, and it's a bit smaller but it's also way cheaper and still pretty big for an e-reader.

However I do have to warn you. I've tried using an e-reader as an alternative for text books a while ago and while it worked for some books. Others were just entirely incompatible. Technology has improved in the last couple of years but don't be surprised if you still have to buy a couple of regular books because of compatibility issues.

Comment: Same experience here. Works for some. EPUB usually isn't a problem at all (even though it depends a little on the file in question). However PDF really is the "watershed format", so to speak. Some readers will have a reflow feature which is supposed to reflow text in the PDF to fit the current zoom level etc. But in general only a larger screen will help and larger screens mean considerably more dots ("pixels") on the screen and higher latency. I've been hooked on E-ink devices since I bought an iRex iLiad around 2007/2008.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sony - DPT Series Digital Paper](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/sony-dpt-series-digital-paper-13-3-16gb-black/6285505.p?skuId=6285505) is in fact the first such product, developed precisely for the reason that many people were in your boat.  Going down your requirements:

- easily put bookmarks on pages; (preferably multiple types of bookmarks)

Not sure

- easily go to chapters based on contents section;

Yes

- easily switch back and forth bookmarked pages, or between chapters; (preferably easily switch between pdfs)

Yes to between chapters; not sure for others

- draw notes in existing pdf files with a pen.

Yes

- easily go through such notes or bookmarks.

No

- Easily transfer files to the tablet via wifi

Yes

- Bonuses: taking notes in a note-taking app.

Yes

- doesn't necessarily have to do anything else (e.g. no youtube, email, etc)

Its functionality other than what you can write on the screen is very limited.